# Flutter kiosk mode without user confirmation

Tags: flutter, kiosk-mode

I'm using "kiosk_mode" (0.2.1) package in my Flutter app on my tablet. At app start I activate the kiosk mode, but the user gets prompted to confirm whether he wants to activate it. And after activating, clicking back button shows the message explaining how to exit kiosk mode.

Is there a way to prevent this functionality? I don't want any user prompt or instructions how to exit the app. Can this even be achieved since these are system dialogues?

I have the app set as an admin app, do I need to add a special policy for this?

I'm using Android 8.0

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge this is not possible with the kiosk_mode package.

This message is likely designed as a safety feature to ensure that users are not unintentionally locked into the application without a means of exiting. It's worth noting that this is generally good practice when developing applications that employ kiosk mode, as it ensures that users retain control over their device.

However, if you have a legitimate use case that requires suppressing this message, you may have to modify the package itself.

Here are general steps you might follow:

1. First, you need to clone the package repository or download the package source code from pub.dev.
2. Once you have the source code, look for the file(s) where the kiosk mode is implemented. This will likely be in the Android implementation since you're specifically looking to change behavior on Android.
3. Look for the function that triggers the kiosk mode and the associated hint message. Once you find the relevant function, comment out or remove the code that triggers the message. Be careful while doing this to ensure that you don't accidentally remove or modify any other important functionality.
4. After modifying the code, you can use your local version of the package in your Flutter project. To do this, specify the path to your local package version in your pubspec.yaml file:

   ```
   dependencies:
     kiosk_mode:
       path: ../path_to_your_local_package
   ```
5. Now, when you run `flutter pub get`, Flutter will use your local version of the kiosk mode package, which includes your modification to suppress the hint message.

Remember, this is a general guideline and it may not directly apply to the kiosk_mode package if the package implementation is different. It's also worth noting that modifying packages in this way means you're responsible for maintaining your modified version, and you may miss out on updates and bug fixes provided by the package maintainers.